# Delete coreData object from another view

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I want to delete a coreData object from another view with an if-condition.

So in viewControllerA there's the entity **Buy** used with the attribute **cellName**. 
And viewControllerB contains a tableView and the coreData entity **List**. When the user deletes a cell in viewControllerB the object of viewControllerA which has **cellName (viewControllerA) = name of the deleted cell (viewControllerB)** should also be deleted.
Maybe someone could help me...

Comment: There may be something I'm missing here but you could probably just have VCA register for a notification and VCB send out the notification when core data has been updated then VCA can just refresh and pick up the new state of core data

Comment: I could be...but as I'm very new to all this I don't know much about coreData, notification,... maybe you can give me a code example and I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a couple of options including a custom delegate but a possibility to start would be through notifications

In your viewControllerA you would register for a notification in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(shouldUpdateDisplay:) 
    name:@"SHOULD_UPDATE_DISPLAY"
    object:nil];
```

NOTE: in your dealloc method you should remove yourself from observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Then implement the method:

```
- (void) shouldUpdateDisplay:(NSNotification *) notification
{
     [_table reloadData]; // do your updates 
}
```

In VCB you would send that notification when an element was deleted and the other view controller should know about it:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:@"SHOULD_UPDATE_DISPLAY" 
    object:self];
```

Comment: I tried to delete all objects in VCA when the notification is sent: `- (void) shouldUpdateDisplay:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.list count]-1; i++) {
        [context deleteObject:[self.list objectAtIndex:i]];
         [self.tableView reloadData]; // do your updates
    
    }
    }`
 But it doesn't work

Comment: Its going to be impossible for me to help you about exact implementation from the info you have given. I would just make sure that that you are calling this function correctly first. Is the viewcontroller that needs to update visible when this notification is received

Comment: Yes...the viewController which sends the notification is visible, the one which receive it is invisible

Comment: Have you tried just recollecting the core data every time your viewcontroller calls viewWillAppear? This would mean that every time it becomes visible it would update itself and maybe solve your problem